# Multidimensional Associative Array (PHP)

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm new to arrays in PHP and am trying to wrap my mind around how to make a multidimensional associative array. I'd like the array to look like this when I use print_r:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [alert] => alert [email] => Test ) )
```

Instead I get this:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [alert] => Array ( [email] => Test ) ) )
```

The code I'm using is this:

```
$alert_array = array();

$alert_array[]["alert"]["email"] = "Test";
```

I thought trying something like this would work, but obviously my syntax is a bit off. I think I'm somewhat on the right track though?:

```
$alert_array[][["alert"]["email"]] = "Test";
```

Thank for your help (sorry if this is super basic, I couldn't find any questions that addressed this exactly)!

Comment: Try with `array_push`.

Comment: @elclanrs, I still don't know how to push just the 'email' value or just the 'alert' value with array_push?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
$alert_array = array();
$alert_array[] = array('alert' => 'alert', 'email' => 'Test');
...
var_dump($alert_array);
```

In your case you'd have to specify `key` like so:

```
$alert_array[$key]["alert"] = "alert";
$alert_array[$key]["email"] = "Test";
```

You'd have to have a loop with counter too.

If you're using PHP 5.4+ you could use short array syntax:

```
$alert_array = [];
$alert_array[] = ['alert' => 'alert', 'email' => 'Test'];
```

Comment: Oh wow, perfect. Way simpler than I thought, I didn't realize it could be done in such a basic way (I was way overthinking). Thanks! (btw, I'll accept your answer in a couple minutes when it allows)

Comment: @MxmastaMills you're welcome, ask anything while you're here :)

Comment: Another quick question for you, I'm looking to 'push' new objects to the array with this method. I tried to use array_push($alert_array, 'alert' => 'alert', 'email' => 'Test'); but that didn't work (I'm assuming this is because of the second comma). I'm basically trying to add objects to the end of the array as my loop runs...

Comment: @MxmastaMills you should only use `array_push` if you are pushing more than one element (array) at a time, otherwise `$array[] = $value`. If you post your code I can probably help you better. You can use "my answer" in loop without problem.

Comment: Ok, it's pretty complex code so I'll put together a simplified version of it and add it above (unless you'd prefer that I add it as a new question).

Comment: @MxmastaMills You can just paste via http://pastebin.com/, no need to make a mess out of Q&A.

Comment: totally my bad. The code you have there is actually what I did have in my code (the version I put on pastebin was what I had mistakenly edited). Your code is only returning one result when there should be two. I know that it loops through it twice because right before the $alert_array[], I put a line that is `echo "test";` and it echoes 'test' two times but only one array element...

Answer (score 2):

if you put an already existing Array inside a new Array using [array function](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_array.asp) , then your result will be multi-dimensional array

```
    $alert_array = array();
    $alert_array[] = array('alert' => 'alert', 'email' => 'Test');
    print_r($alert_array);

    /* result will be
    Array ( [0] => Array ( [alert] => alert [email] => Test ) )
    */
```

In this case, result will be one-dimensional array

```
$alert_array = array();
while($variable = mysqli_fetch_assoc($something)) {
$alert_array[] = $variable;
}
```

please also refer [array function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array.php)

Answer (score 0):

All associative relationships:

```
$alert_array = ["alert"  => ["email"  => "test"],
                "act"    => ["phone"  => "data"],
                "report" => ["pager"  => "yes" ],
                "advise" => ["letter" => "no"  ] ];
```