# How can I sort by variable within a foreach loop (php)?

Tags: php

in my for each loop I want to sort my options by the value of my variable `$total` resp. by the `data-total`:

```
     <select>
                   <option data-total="0" value="" selected>--</option>
                   <?php 

                    $pdo = Database::connect();


                    $sql = "SELECT  *  FROM table_a;" ;

                    foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {

                            $a = $row['a'];
                            $number_a = $row['number_a'];               

                            $sql2 = "SELECT  *  FROM table_b WHERE a = '$a';" ;
                            $number_b = 0;

                            foreach ($pdo->query($sql2) as $row2) {
                                $number_b+= $row2['number']; 
                            }

                            $total = $number_a - $number_b;

                            echo '<option data-total="'.$total.'" value="'.$a.'">'.$a;

                    }

                    Database::disconnect();

                        ?>                                                          
     </select>
```

Is this possible? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your for loop do something like this

```
$total_arr = array();
foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {

                            $a = $row['a'];
                            $number_a = $row['number_a'];               

                            $sql2 = "SELECT  *  FROM table_b WHERE a = '$a';" ;
                            $number_b = 0;

                            foreach ($pdo->query($sql2) as $row2) {
                                $number_b+= $row2['number']; 
                            }

                            $total = $number_a - $number_b;
                            $total_arr[$a] = $total;

                    }

arsort($total_arr);
foreach ($total_arr as $key => $val) {
    echo '<option data-total="'.$val.'" value="'.$key.'">'.$key;
}
```

Comment: One question: `$a` now doesn't have the right value. It has now for all options the same value, but in my code above it had the right value.

Comment: Thank you! But this doesn't give me the value of `$a` it gives me a `0`and a `1`

Comment: do I need a multidimensional array for this?

Comment: I cannot find what you have changed unfortunately

Comment: Have you tried this one ? changed to `arsort($total_arr);`

Comment: Last time we used `sort()` function which was converting keys to index as you were saying `it gives me a 0and a 1`, so changed to `arsort()`.

Comment: And if I would use more values, like for example also `$number_a`, would I write it like this: `$total_arr[$a,$number_a] = $total;`?

Comment: No, you cant do like this. You could either try multidimensional associative arrays http://stackoverflow.com/a/18648466/4725592