# Using an array in PHP to echo values based on previous results

Tags: php, arrays

I'm taking 4 dimensions from my DB (dimension1 etc) and then running an if statement so that I can not only display the dimension to the user, but then corresponding feedback. So as any type of 'active' learner for example receives the same feedback. As a result in my DB table 'ilsFeedback' I want to extract answerType and studentDefinition so that I can match the 8 learning types with the corresponding feedback where necessary. I have been able to display the dimension, and the type of feedback each user needs. Struggling to complete the rest in terms of extracting the required definition. Any help would be apprenticed. Thanks

```
<?php

    $dbQuery = $db->prepare("select dimension1, dimension2, dimension3, dimension4 FROM indexLearningStyle WHERE studentNumber = '".$currentUser."'");
    $dbQuery-> execute();

    while ($dbRow = $dbQuery->fetch (PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $dimension1 = $dbRow["dimension1"];
    $dimension2 = $dbRow["dimension2"];
    $dimension3 = $dbRow["dimension3"];
    $dimension4 = $dbRow["dimension4"]; 

    }

    if  ($dimension1 == "Strongly Active"){
        $displayDimension1 = 'active';

    }
    elseif ($dimension1 == "Moderately Active") {
        $displayDimension1 = 'active';

    }
    elseif ($dimension1 == "Mildly Active") {
        $displayDimension1 = 'active';

    }
    elseif ($dimension1 == "Strongly Reflective") {
        $displayDimension1 = 'reflective';

    }
    elseif ($dimension1 == "Moderately Reflective") {
        $displayDimension1 = 'reflective';

    }
    elseif ($dimension1 == "Mildly Reflective") {
        $displayDimension1 = 'reflective';

    }

    if  ($dimension2 == "Strongly Sensing"){
        $displayDimension2 = 'sensing';

    }
    elseif ($dimension2 == "Moderately Sensing") {
        $displayDimension2 = 'sensing';

    }
    elseif ($dimension2 == "Mildly Sensing") {
        $displayDimension2 = 'sensing';

    }
    elseif ($dimension2 == "Strongly Intuitive") {
        $displayDimension2 = 'sensing';

    }
    elseif ($dimension2 == "Moderately Intuitive") {
        $displayDimension2 = 'sensing';

    }
    elseif ($dimension2 == "Mildly Intuitive") {
        $displayDimension2 = 'sensing';

    }

    if  ($dimension3 == "Strongly Visual"){
        $displayDimension3 = 'visual';

    }
    elseif ($dimension3 == "Moderately Visual") {
        $displayDimension3 = 'visual';

    }
    elseif ($dimension3 == "Mildly Visual") {
        $displayDimension3 = 'visual';

    }
    elseif ($dimension3 == "Strongly Verbal") {
        $displayDimension3 = 'verbal';

    }
    elseif ($dimension3 == "Moderately Verbal") {
        $displayDimension3 = 'verbal';

    }
    elseif ($dimension3 == "Mildly Verbal") {
        $displayDimension3 = 'verbal';

    }

    if  ($dimension4 == "Strongly Sequential"){
        $displayDimension4 = 'sequential';

    }
    elseif ($dimension4 == "Moderately Sequential") {
        $displayDimension4 = 'sequential';

    }
    elseif ($dimension4 == "Mildly Sequential") {
        $displayDimension4 = 'sequential';

    }
    elseif ($dimension4 == "Strongly Global") {
        $displayDimension4 = 'global';

    }
    elseif ($dimension4 == "Moderately Global") {
        $displayDimension4 = 'global';

    }
    elseif ($dimension4 == "Mildly Global") {
        $displayDimension4 = 'global';

    }

    $dbQuery = $db->prepare("select studentDefinition FROM ilsFeedback");
    $dbQuery-> execute();

    $result_array = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($dbQuery))
    {
        $result_array[]=$row;
    }

    print_r($result_array);


?>
```

Comment: What is a student definition? how does it relate to the current dimensions? And why do all the dimensions (eg mildly, strongly etc) output the same thing? eg surely "if reflective then = reflective"?

Comment: Check this answer on multidimensional associative arrays: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18648413/multidimensional-associative-array-php

Comment: Each learning type (active, reflective etc) has a corresponding studentDefinition I wish to display. Whilst a user can be mildy - strongly of any learning type, the feedback for all remains the same. Hope this helps.